# How to get Range of values in each loop in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I am having below columns in my excel(Sheet1)

```
  Service    June   July  Aug
   ENG        10     20    30
   GMO        40     30    20
   SUV        10     20    10
   ENG        30     70    90
   SUV        40     30    10
```

Here I want to read all columns with "ENG" or "SUV" (Repeated cells) and must add their associated values and automate to next sheet , sheet2.
Like..,
Example: If I take ENG I must get total of ENG in June, July and Aug and this data must be populated.
For this I am using code as below.

```
 Dim E As String
 For Each c In Worksheets("Mktg.Effort").Range("A2:A20")
 If StrComp(c.Value, "eng") Then
 gmo1 = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(?),Range(?))
 End If
 Next c
```

Here I am unable to get Range of those associated ENG cell values. How do I get those values?
Any help please

INPUT:

```
       Service    June   July  Aug
        ENG        10     20    30
        GMO        40     30    20
        SUV        10     20    10
        ENG        30     70    90
        SUV        40     30    10
```

OUTPUT:

```
    ENG       40    90  40
    GMO       40    30  20
    SUV       50    50  20
```

This must be output

Comment: why do you not just use sumif?

Comment: Instead of SUM you want me to take SUMIF ? I am not sure.. help me here

Comment: Try it, it is just a formula

Comment: I would create a nominal variable to denote the month, then use sumif

Comment: @SwethaReddy there's also a VBA option (depends which your prefer)

Comment: @SwethaReddy add examples of input data and corresponding desired output, along with where (which sheet) output is expected

Comment: @user3598756 Edit my question

Comment: @ShaiRado any help please.., I need to read Cell values based on condition. If condition satisfies I must read those row columns.

Comment: @SwethaReddy try my code in edited answer

Comment: http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html

Answer (score 0):

Do a sum if, with an offset for the sum range based on the month, using a date in E1 for the month to sum, then using your example data in A to D, `=SUMIF($A$2:$A$6,"ENG",OFFSET($B$2:$B$6,0,MONTH($E$1)-month($B$1))`

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to use the VBA option:

You can add more cases to test for your "Service names" or add other `Case` scenarios.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SumRows()

Dim lrow        As Long
Dim Col         As Long
Dim gmo1        As Long
Dim LastCol     As Long
Dim LastRow     As Long

Dim RangetoSum  As Range
Dim RangeCond   As Range

With Worksheets("Mktg.Effort")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For Col = 2 To .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set RangetoSum = Range(Cells(2, Col), Cells(LastRow, Col))
        Set RangeCond = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastRow, 1))

        ' for debug purposes only
        ' Debug.Print RangetoSum.Address
        ' Debug.Print RangeCond.Address

        ' print "ENG" sum per month 2 rows below the last row with data >> modify to your location needs
        Cells(LastRow + 2, Col) = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(RangeCond, "ENG", RangetoSum)

        ' print "SUV" sum per month 3 rows below the last row with data >> modify to your location needs
        Cells(LastRow + 3, Col) = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(RangeCond, "SUV", RangetoSum)

    Next Col

    ' Add headers for Sum
    Cells(LastRow + 2, 1) = "ENG (sum of)"
    Cells(LastRow + 3, 1) = "SUV (sum of)"

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: gmo1 = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(lrow, 2), Cells(lrow, .Cells(lrow, LastCol))))
Here I want Sum ( where ENG row appears , that corrosponding June value + Where NEXT ENG row appears, that corresponding June Value)
Example: In A2 if ENG is there and B2 June value is there for 1st row
and A3 if other ENG is there and B3 June value is there I want to sum those values..
So, here How can I SUM those values which are appearing multiple times, how to call them

Comment: @SwethaReddy , my bad, I didn't understad your post, I summed the row, not colums, I'll modify my answer soon...

Comment: Thanks for help.., But still my req is diff I gues..
Actully My Real Time excel is like below
     Service(Header)     June(Header)
      Engg(A2)                1064(AF2)

Here my cells are at defined places.. like 1st column and AF2
I think I need to append Rownumber to AF so that I can get correct

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim helpCol As Long
    Dim cell As Range

    With Worksheets("Mktg.Effort")
        helpCol = .UsedRange.Offset(, .UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column
        With .Range("A2", .Cells(.rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
            .Offset(, helpCol).Value = .Value
            With .Offset(, helpCol)
                .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlNo
                For Each cell In .SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants)
                    cell.Offset(, 1) = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(.Offset(, -helpCol), cell.Value, .Offset(, -helpCol + 1))
                    cell.Offset(, 2) = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(.Offset(, -helpCol), cell.Value, .Offset(, -helpCol + 2))
                    cell.Offset(, 3) = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(.Offset(, -helpCol), cell.Value, .Offset(, -helpCol + 3))
                Next cell
            End With
            With .Resize(, 4)
                .ClearContents
                .Value = .Offset(, helpCol).Value
                .Offset(, helpCol).ClearContents
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @SwethaReddy, it'd be nice of you to give proper feedbacks to people trying to help you